How to close all files and ports from parent process
I have an HTTP server (source code not accessible and cannot be substituted at this time) running on my Linux machine, which can be configured to execute any commands on requested. However, the HTTP server will not close all its files and sockets before external command execution, and leaving the external program having unexpected behavior (like listening the :80 port). Is there any way to manually close these files and sockets then run the external program? Or wrap the program with shell script that do something to close them?

Lingering sockets and open file handles from the web server imply that it is starting with a fork() and exec().  Classic way to start a child process, but it typically shares the security context of the web server so be careful what you run.
Unclear as to what you could do in an external script to some arbitrary web server. In theory could close all possible file descriptors, but seems slow.
Implement FastCGI or similar framework that runs external programs from a web server. Write FastCGI aware scripts to wrap whatever needs to be done.   Start the FastCGI process not from the web server, so better isolation can be achieved. Think php-fpm, but could be something else not written in php.
Any service manager could start the worker processes separately from the web server. Or perhaps on systemd Linux, use socket activation and have it start on demand. Possibly as a different unprivileged user, and without needing to be a child process of the web server.
Of course if the web server doesn't support something like FastCGI this won't work. Might not be too bad to continue as is, I cannot think of an obvious way to take advantage of those open sockets. Assuming there were some controls over the programs run, and they were trusted.

Currently we are running some OpenResty servers. Even though I hate it, there are no plans at present to switch to any other technology. At first, we benefited from running anything by calling resty.shell.run, until we found the opening port issue. The remaining children processes that did not exited may prevent the server to restart, reporting "port is in use".
